# I want to select the top 50 rows from SQL table and display them newest to oldest

Tags: php, sql

```
    <?php
mysql_select_db("mgshuheb") or die("No such database");
$str = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC";
$rs = mysql_query($str);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

      echo '<span class="name">' . $row["name"] . '</span>'."<br />";
      echo $row["post"] . "<br />";
      echo $row["time"] . "<br /><br />";
      }
?>
```

Here is what I have at the moment. When I type in `SELECT TOP 50 * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC;` it keeps bringing up an error.

Comment: Which error do you have?

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, use `limit` instead of `top`:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    posts 
ORDER BY 
        id DESC
LIMIT   50
```

Comment: You should order by `time` not by `id` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should have to put limit on query

```
<?php
    $str = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,50";
 ?>
```